# This is for my Rock, Paper Scissors game in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, syntax-error

```
while True: print("Enter Choice \n 2 for Rock \n 2 for Paper \n 3 for Sciccors") break
```

I expected that the `break` statement will break the while loop but it didn't. It showed me `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop`

Comment: Is all of your code in one single line?

Comment: use proper indentation of code, as in the answers given

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your python code is not formatted by putting each on separate lines.

So this:

```
while True: Print("Enter Choice \n 2 for Rock \n 2 for Paper \n 3 for Sciccors") break
```

should be this:

```
while True:
     print("Enter Choice \n 2 for Rock \n 2 for Paper \n 3 for Sciccors")
     break
```

Gives the output:

```
Enter Choice 
 2 for Rock 
 2 for Paper 
 3 for Sciccors
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to either break line join different statements with `;`. For example:

```py
while True: 
    print("Enter Choice \n 1 for Rock \n 2 for Paper \n 3 for Scissors")
    break
```

Or

```py
while True: print("Enter Choice \n 1 for Rock \n 2 for Paper \n 3 for Scissors"); break
```